# Tableau Count Records Between Date Ranges

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to get a count of records between dates.
My data has records from 01/01/2020 to 04/01/2020.
I have set up two parameters, Start-date & End-date
I only want to count the records that are between my start (01/01/2020) and end date (01/31/2020).

```
Sample Data
Sheet_ID  Supervisor_ID   Category_ID   Date
OB-111       1111            1          01/01/2020
OB-112       1111            4          03/01/2020
OB-113       1111            2          01/01/2020
OB-114       2222            2          01/01/2020
OB-115       2222            2          01/21/2020
```

I am trying to show the following

```
Supervisor_ID   Category_ID     Count
1111              1              1
1111              2              1
2222              2              2
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Create a calculated as follows:

```
IF [Date]>=[StartDate] AND [Date]<=[EndDate] THEN 1 END
```

Sum this field to get the count.

Comment: Or save typing 5 whole characters with the near equivalent expression INT([Date]>=[StartDate] AND [Date]<=[EndDate])